# Convert LiveData to RxJava observable

Tags: android, rx-java, android-livedata

I have 2 views: EditText with amount (which should not be empty) and agreement checkbox (which should be checked). I also have 2 MutableLive data variables which represent states of this views inside my ViewModel.

I want to combine this 2 variables in Observables and use Observable.combineLattest to enable/disable my "Send" button.

I have found library which called android.arch.lifecycle:reactivestreams and converted my LiveData to Publishers, but I cannot use them in Observable.combineLattest because org.reactivestreams because Publisher is org.reactivestreams interface and Observable.combineLattest accept observable source.

I read some articles but they all refer to this library.

Currently I have code like this:

```
override fun onViewCreated(view: View, savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState)

        ...

        dispossable = Observable.combineLatest(
                LiveDataReactiveStreams.toPublisher(this, vm.amount),
                LiveDataReactiveStreams.toPublisher(this, vm.isAgreementChecked),
                BiFunction<String, Boolean, Boolean> { amount, isChecked ->
                    amount.isNotEmpty() && isChecked
                })
    }
```

Is anyone know good workaround to convert LiveData to Observable. 
Thanks in advance.

Comment: `Flowable. combineLatest` ?

Comment: any ObservableSource

Comment: you need a `Publisher`. `Flowable` is a `Publisher`

Comment: You can use `Observable.fromPublisher(LiveDataReactiveStreams.toPublisher(...))` if you absolutely need an observable.

Comment: Yes, thanks a lot. I'am (out of habit) searched for solution with Observable and not remember about Flowable and publisher.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As Blackbelt rightly said - instead of using Observable for combineLatest (and other operators like Zip, Debounce etc) I can use Flowable from LiveData with:

```
LiveDataReactiveStreams.toPublisher(/*lifecycle*/, /*observable Field*/).
```

So my current solution looks like this:

```
disposable = Flowable.combineLatest(
    LiveDataReactiveStreams.toPublisher(this, vm.amount),
    LiveDataReactiveStreams.toPublisher(this, vm.isAgreementChecked),
    BiFunction<String, Boolean, Boolean> { amount, isChecked ->
        amount.isNotEmpty() && isChecked
    }).subscribe { isDataValid ->
        vm.setIsDataValid(isDataValid)
    }
```

Thanks again :)

Answer (score 1):

An alternative solution might be (I needed this because WorkManager only returns LiveData):

```
fun getWorkData(): Flowable<List<WorkInfo>> {
    val workDataLiveData = WorkManager.getInstance().getWorkInfosByTagLiveData("TAG")
    Flowable.create({emitter -> 
        val observer = Observer> { emitter.onNext(it) }
        val disposable = disposeInUiThread { workDataLiveData.removeObserver(observer) }
        emitter.setDisposable(disposable)
        workDataLiveData.observeForever(observer)
    }, BackpressureStrategy.LATEST)
}

private fun disposeInUiThread(action: Action): Disposable {
        return Disposables.fromAction {
            if (Looper.getMainLooper() == Looper.myLooper()) {
                action.run()
            } else {
                val inner = AndroidSchedulers.mainThread().createWorker()
                inner.schedule {
                    try {
                        action.run()
                    } catch (e: Exception) {
                        Timber.e(e, "Could not unregister receiver in UI Thread")
                    }

                    inner.dispose()
                }
            }
        }
    }
```